# Bash - get return code of background process only if it died

Tags: bash

I have a simple server client test. I start the server as a background process, wait for 5 seconds and then start the client. Like so

```
server > /tmp/serverlog 2>&1 &

sleep 5

client > /tmp/clientlog 2>&1

ret=$?

cat /tmp/serverlog
cat /tmp/clientlog

exit ret
```

Sometimes, the server will fail to start. In that case, I want to exit with the exit code from the server and not start the client.

I can check if the server is alive with `kill -0`. But I can't get the exit code. I can use `wait` to wait for the server to finish but if the server doesn't fail, then `wait` will never return.

How can I check if the background server process died and get the return code only if it died?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `kill -0` to see if the server died, and if it did, *then* use `wait` to get its exit status.

```
server > /tmp/serverlog 2>&1 & server_pid=$!

sleep 5

if ! kill -0 $server_pid; then
    wait $server_pid
    exit  # uses exit status of previous command, which is exit status of server
fi

client > /tmp/clientlog 2>&1

ret=$?

cat /tmp/serverlog
cat /tmp/clientlog

exit $ret
```

It shouldn't be a real issue, but be aware of the race condition of the server's process ID being available for reuse after it exists, but before you use it with `kill` and `wait`.

Comment: Re: the caveat at the end, is that true even in a noninteractive shell with job control turned off? (Honest question: I really don't know if the default SIGCHILD handler still does a `waitpid` when job control isn't enabled).

Comment: I thought `wait` had to be called when the process was still running. Thanks!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I assume so, though I'm not sure how to test it; I don't feel like churning through a bunch of processes until I get a duplicate :). (But if I use `wait` for an obviously non-child process ID, I get an exit status of 127, not because the process necessarily exited, but because `wait` itself set `$?` to 127. So there are other issues that I'm not sure you can work around reliably.)

Comment: A quick test suggests it should be true - run something like `echo $- ; sleep 1 & pid=$! ; echo $pid ; sleep 10 ; wait ; echo $?` and you can confirm that even with job control disabled the `sleep 1` doesn't leave a zombie so its pid is hypothetically available for reuse.

Comment: @abattleofwords, when a process exits, it leaves a "tombstone" in the process table, which calling `wait` will return the data from and remove. That tombstone is what a "zombie" process is -- a marker for a dead process whose parent never received information about _how_ it died. What complicates this a little is that interactive shells with job control on will do the wait call as soon as they get a notice that a child died, and put the information in a table _local to that shell_ rather than keeping it only in the kernel's process table.

Comment: @abattleofwords, ...it would seem, that from what tjm3772 said above, this is true not only of interactive shells but noninteractive ones as well.

Comment: I tried calling `wait` on a process started outside the shell and it failed with `wait: pid 30396 is not a child of this shell`

So even if the PID is reused, the wait command will fail and the negative outcome is the wrong error code. Is that right?

Comment: @abattleofwords, `wait "$server_pid"` (note added quotes to protect against word splitting with unusual values of `IFS`) is completely safe, and will always return the correct status of the exited child process (even if the PID has since been reused).  That is because Bash keeps a record of the exit status of its child processes and always uses that  instead of doing a system `wait`.  A Bash `wait` can give unexpected results if the program causes PID reuse of its own child PIDs by running huge numbers of background processes, but that is not a problem in this case.

Comment: As explained in my previous comment, `wait "$server_pid"` is safe.  `if ! kill -0 "$server_pid"; then` is not safe.  The PID may have been reused by another process.  (I've tested this, though I had to use a sleep value much larger than `5` on my test system.)  One way to make it safe is to enable job control (`set -o monitor`) and use `if ! kill -0 %% 2>/dev/null; then`.  The redirection to `/dev/null` is to silence an error message about    an exited job.